# How to display ManyToManyField field values from a ForeignKey in Django template ?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-orm

I looked in the QuestSet API and tried to find the answer. But i guess i am misinterpreting the distinction between a Manager and an instance.

I have the following model...

```
class Target(model.Model):
   group = models.ManyToManyField(Group, null=True)
   group_name = models.ManyToManyField(GroupName, null=True)
   ...

class Group(models.Model):
   value = models.CharField(null=True)
```

And so on is defined for all the ManyToMany relations in the Target Model.

Now, i have a reference to the Target Model itself from another model as follows.

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
   targetID = models.ForeignKey(Target, null=True)
   name = models.CharField(null=True)
```

In my template for the Schedule model, I want to be able to display the values of the ManyToManyFields which are referenced in the ForeignKey (i.e the Target).

When i write the following,

```
o = Schedule.objects.get(name = 'O_123')
o.targetID --->  This gives me the ID of the ForeignKey field
```

I want to be able to display the value of all the field which are there in the Target Model with reference to the name(i.e. O_123), For this i tried the following,

```
o.targetID.group
```

this displays "django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x1f2e850"

Can someone help me understand what am I misinterpreting. Thanks.

Comment: `o.targetID.group` gives you a queryset. You need to do `o.targetID.group.all()` and iterate through the objects in a loop. [More here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some misconceptions.

> o.targetID --->  This gives me the ID of the ForeignKey field

No. `o.targetID` gives you the *actual Target object* that is related via your ForeignKey. That's why you should not call the field anythingID: it should just be called `target`.

Now, this is possible because that is the many-to-one side of the FK relationship: ie, for each Schedule, there is only one Target. But from Target to Group there is a many-to-many relationship. So `o.targetID.group` refers to *many* groups (again, naming conventions help: you should probably call this field `groups`).

So Django gives you a Manager object: basically, just the same as when you do `Schedule.objects`. Just as with that latter case, you can do `all()` to get all of the elements to iterate over, or `get(criteria=value)` to get a specific one, or even `filter(criteria=value)` to get a filtered queryset.

In your case, you probably want:

```
for group in o.targetID.group.all():
    print group.my_field_value
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I knew i was not understanding something correctly. Can you also tell me how do i proceed to the following problem. I have a form wherein i display a checkbox from my model with some ID, on selecting a particular ID it displays the the rest of the field from the same model. I think i will have to use ajax so that i get the table displayed on the same page. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Yes, sounds like you'll need Ajax. If you have any specific queries, you should open a new question.

Comment: Ok..I shall do that.. Thanks!